# How does ARC deal with local variable within the method?

Tags: ios, objective-c

For example,

```
- (void) method
{
    NSString *string = @"This is a string.";

}
```

Do I need to add

> string = nil;

at the end of the method in order to let ARC release it?

Situation may be different in non-literal object such as

```
- (void) method
{
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] init];

}
```

Do I need to add at the end

> data = nil;

to release it?

Comment: Local variables are deallocated when they go out of scope.  You don't need to set them to `nil`.

Comment: `NSInteger` isn't an object type. You don't need to make a pointer to `NSInteger` to store an integer value. You definitely shouldn't attempt to store `5` to a *pointer to* `NSInteger`. In any case, since ARC only deals with object types, it does nothing with either `NSInteger` or `NSInteger*`.

Comment: I edited my question due to the improper NSInteger to indicate the question. Thank you for pointing out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to nil it, but ARC doesn't release it either.  Since it's a literal, it's statically allocated in the app's binary.  It's never released.

```
- (void)method {

    NSString *string = @"I'm never released because I'm statically allocated";
    NSString *arcReleasesMeAfterMyLastSourceRef = [NSString stringWithString:string];
}
```